# How can I delete a row from array and then add a new row to dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, csv, dictionary

I have an array called teams[] which I filled with data from a csv file (the csv has a team and a score):

```
teams = []
with open("2018m.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)

        for row in reader:
            row["rating"] = int(row["rating"])
            teams.append(row)
```

But then I have a dictionary called counts{} where I want to count how many times a team won the championship by a simulation. The thing is that I want to add all the teams from teams[] and then give them a value 0 (cause at first nobody will have any championship) so it will look kind of like this

```
counts {
"Brasil": 0,
"Argentina": 0,
"France": 0
}
```

I need to know how to get only the team row from teams[] and at the same time add it a value of 0. I tought to this with a loop and add teams[i] but I don't know how to just take the team row and also how to give it the value.

HELP BEEN STUCK FOR A WHILE!!

I imagine something like:

```
counts[teams[i]] = 0
```

but i Know it is not possible

Comment: How would you get the team name for each row? Why not create the empty dict just after you create the empty list `teams`, and set the value for the team name as you read the csv file?

Comment: Alternatively just use a `defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```py
counts = {team['team'] : 0 for team in teams}
```

Comment: This assumes the column name for the team name is `"team"`.